# Bind Custom DataGridHeader MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datacontext

I am trying to Bind a `TextBlock` inside the `Header` of a `DataGrid`. However, it doesn't seem to be binding. I've tried setting the **DataContext** to the one of the *root* `Grid`, but it does not fix the problem.

Here is the exemple:

**VIEW**

```
<Window 
       ... 
       Title={Binding Title}> 
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="root">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Initial header";
    }
}
```

**RESULT**
[image: Showcase]

what I want is to be able to write in the `TextBox` and change the header. However, it does seem to be unbinded.

I belive the problem to be with **DataContext**, but I haven't been able to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to Bind the dataContext to the ancestor.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext}" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I'll leave it here.